# not able to drag and drop a button on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a tool that will allow users to create their own html pages. For this i am allowing users to click on different items like button and drag and drop them on required locations. But for some reason the drag and drop is not working. The code attached is only for the button(the other attributes are still to be implemented). The css files are also attached.

`

```
<title>HTML5 Editor</title>
<link href="html editor/business-casual/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="html editor/business-casual/css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type='text/javascript'>
var i = 1;
var bufferCanvas = new Array();
var ButtonArray = [];
ButtonArray.push({
type : "submit",
name: [],
value:[]
});
console.log(ButtonArray);
<!-- Create Button when user clicks on button-->
function createButton(ev)
{
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var button = document.createElement("input");
div=document.createElement('div');
button.type="submit";
button.style.position='absolute';
button.name="Button"+i;
button.value = "Button"+i;
div.appendChild(button);
div.draggable=true;
div.ondragstart="drag(event)";
div.id="draggable";
div.class="draggable ui-widget-content";
var l=i-1;
ButtonArray[l].name.push(div.id);
ButtonArray[l].value.push(button.value);
canvas.appendChild(div);
i++;
}
function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.stopPropagation();
ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev)
{
ev.stopPropagation();
ev.preventDefault();
}
function drop(ev)
{
ev.stopPropagation();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
ev.preventDefault();}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-size: 18px}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="brand">HTML5 EDITOR</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="../business-casual/index.html">Business Casual</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href=:"index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="create.html">Create</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="box">
<div class="col-lg-12" id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Add</a>
<ul>
<li><a name ="textBox" onClick="createTextBox()">Text</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Image</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shapes </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Lines</a></li>
<li><a name="button" onClick="createButton()">Buttons</a><li>
<li><a href="#">Menus</a><li>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul><li><a name="SaveButton" onClick="saveTextAsFile()">Save</a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-header" id ="myCanvas" ondrop="drop(event)"  ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
<footer>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this greate example http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp